# wordpress development flow: browser auto refresh

Tags: wordpress

I want to optimimize my wordpress development flow.
Is there a way to automatically refresh the browser when I save code in my text editor during wordpress dev. I am using MAMP for dev env.
I am looking for something like gulp browserSync for a wordpress dev env.

Answer (score 2):

install browser-sync ( nodejs required )

```
npm install browser-sync -g
```

and then use proxy to add your localhost address and then add files

```
browser-sync start --proxy "localhost" --files "*.php"
```

or

```
browser-sync start --proxy "localhost" --files "*.php, *.css, **/*.php, **/*.css"
```

Comment: is this still relevant in 2020?

Answer (score 0):

I use netbeans IDE for WP development and you can run the code directly from there

click on green arrow at top
then in the new window click on browser
select your browser
url :- enter http://localhost:8888/wordpress/

home page :- should be left blank

after this every time you hot the green arrow you will automatically be taken to the site.

Hope this helps

Take care and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can let the gulp-browsersync sync .php files as well.

```
// Add php extention to your gulp paths
var paths = {
  html: ['*.php', '*.html'],
};

// Then add paths to task
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'localhost/yourporject'
  });
});

// Execute on change
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.html).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: Looks good. But it doesn't work in combination with MAMP. I already have a development server running on localhost: 8888.